# Add new form option is missing from Class Library project

Tags: c#

I've installed visual studio 2022 Community and created a new .Net 6 Class Library project.
I tried to add a new Windows Form as I did in the old VS/.Net version by right clicking the project > add > New windows forms. However, that option is missing. When I right click the project > add > New item, the Windows Forms option is missing as well.

Comment: You need to install the template.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-csharp-winform-visual-studio?force_isolation=true&view=vs-2022

Comment: Pick the correct project template to get started, its name is "Windows Forms Class Library".  Or modify an existing project, right-click it in the Solution Explorer window > Edit Project File > TargetFramework = net6.0-windows and add `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>`